# validate input field for human test

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in java script .any help to validate these to number.

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group"><?php 
                                $a_con=rand(0,9);
                                $b_con=rand(0,9);
                            ?>
             Human Test <?php echo $a_con." + ".$b_con?> = 
                            </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Human Test" class="form-control" name="value_num" required/>
        <input class="input" name="captcha_num_hidden_contact" id="captcha_num_hidden_contact" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a_con+$b_con;?>"/>


    </div>
```

Comment: Why is php not added in tags? and what is it that you need to validate exactly?

Comment: Considering your tags, you want that validation in js, right? But it is a *captch* validation, so it is not nice to make it on client side. It should be done in PHP, imo.

Comment: Krishna Prashatt @when  i have rundam number 5 then i have to put these number in field . i put 7 then show error message

Comment: A captcha with the answer hidden in HTML is not a good idea.

Comment: yunandtidus@can  you help me regarding this